# Alternative definition of the S1 and S2 manifolds (not as embedded manifolds)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, spheres

Can I define the $S^1$ and $S^2$ manifolds as follows? (by using equivalence relations $\sim$)

For $S^1$, let us define in $\mathbb R$ the equivalence class $\sim^1$  by

$x \sim^1 y  \iff \exists k\in\mathbb{Z} :  x-y = 2 k\pi$

Then, $S^1 = \mathbb R/\sim^1 $?

For, $S^2$, let us define $M = S^1 \times [0,\pi]$ and the equivalence relation $\sim^2$ defined by

$(x,y) \sim^2 (x', y') \iff \{y=y'=0 \, \, \rm{ or} \,\, y=y'=\pi\}$

Then, $S^2 = M/\sim^2$?

And, I guess, something similar for $S^n$.

Comment: Do you mean to *quotient out* by the equivalence relation? You should define the relation somewhere outside the set, and then quotient out, to make the relation $\sim$ an equality $=$.

Comment: Why do you wish to define the circle as a set of equivalence classes of real numbers?

Comment: Keshav, do you mean something like it is now?

Comment: Well, I was just thinking on defining the circle not as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: What did you try to prove that these quotient spaces are indeed homeomorphic to $S^1$ and $S^2$ respectively?

Comment: $\sim_1$ is an equivalence relation, not an equivalence class. right now, $\sim_1$ is not a reflexive relation, so it’s not an equivalence relation. one way to fix this is to say that $x\sim_1 y$ if and only if there is an integer $k$ such that $y-x=2\pi k$. then $\sim_1$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$ and (somebody please correct me if im wrong) $\mathbb{R}/\sim_1$ is homeomorphic to the interval $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: anyway, $S^1$ can be defined as $[0,1]/\sim$ where $\sim = \{(x,x) : x\in (0,1)\}\cup\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$

Comment: But following the answer of another post, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/688866/1029883, $S^1$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,2\pi)$ because the first one is compact and the second one is not.

Comment: @CSquared The quotient topology gives birth to something homeomorphic to the circle, not $[0,2\pi)$ and its usual topology

Comment: @Didier right. thank you for correcting me. the complex exponential gives the homeomorphism.